# UIStackView inside UIScrollView with dynamically changing items

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, ios9, uistackview

I'm trying to have a `UIStackView` in a `UIScrollView` with changing content in the `UIStackView` as shown below in the image. How ever I don't manage to get it to work properly. When I launch my app it does not scroll and only 10 items are shown in the stack view, not the 20 I expected. Also it does not scroll all the way down of the `UIStackView`.

Note it's important that this can work on both iPhone and iPad even when rotated.

[image: Scene]

I have the following code in my View Controller (that's all):

```
@IBOutlet weak var stackView: UIStackView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for i in 1 ... 20 {
        let vw = UILabel()
        vw.text = "Holiday #\(i)"
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(vw);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using this as a foundation:
https://github.com/oliverfoggin/AnimalBrowser

The code remains the same, but I changed around a bit on the scene and now it works!

[image: Scene]

Comment: Thanks for sharing, altho the project you shared didn't directly fixed my issue it helped me get guidance with a more complex issue that I am facing.